# How long will 'scrollToItemAtIndexPath' method take if animated?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to do something exactly after finishing the animation in UICollectionView by calling 'scrollToItemAtIndexPath' method, but i don`t know how long will it take. Any documentation mentioned that?

PS.I knew 'do something with delay (maybe 1s/2s)' is a workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView and UICollectionViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate.  So you can use your UICollectionView delegate's scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Running into another problem,how can i tell the following two situations: 1,The target item is fully visible.2,The target item is partly visible? Because the 'scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation' method is only called after scrolling, and if the target item is already visible, then nothing happened.

Comment: In this case, before calling scrollToItemAtIndexPath, you can check if the [collectionView visibleCells] already contains the specific cell to scroll to.  If yes, then do something.  If no, then the animation will be triggered and scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation will be called.

Comment: I have already added the check method, but i want to 'do something' with the target item to be fully visible, and calling ‘scrollToItemAtIndexPath’ while the target item is party visible（is one of  collectionView.visibleCells and  the check method returns YES） will not trigger ‘scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation’.As i figured out a workaround with double check to deal with the situation.i will accept you answer, thanks for giving directions :)